# how to get video id from clicking YouTube search page link in a webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have a webview in which I present YouTube search page. (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=)
I want to receive the video id of the clip the user pressed.
so far I have tried the following without success:

1. use of shouldOverrideUrlLoading - isn't being called when pressing on the video clip in search

```
    public WebViewClient getWebViewClient()
    {
        return new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("TAG","called overide url");
                if (url.startsWith(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL)) {
                    setVideoIdFromLink(url);

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("GABI","url:"+url);
                }
                return false;
            }
            /*
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url){

                if(url.startsWith(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL)){
                    setVideoIdFromLink(url);
                }
            }*/
        };
    }
```

2. setting an onTouchListener - method always return type 0 extras null

```
    private OnTouchListener linkClickTouch()
    {
        return new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                        if(clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                            v.performClick();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            };
        }
```

the click action:

```
private OnClickListener linkClick()
    {
        
        return new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                
                final WebView webview = (WebView) v;
                final WebView.HitTestResult result = webview.getHitTestResult();
                Log.d("TAG", "result:"+result.getType()+"\nextras:"+
                result.getExtra());
                
                
                if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
                    
                }

                if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
                
                }

                if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE) {
                
                }

                
            }
        };
    }
```

I know I can probably use the YouTube API but I want to accomplish that without building a search activity which will display results only to find the id, when a decent search page already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after many trial and error:
shouldOverrideUrlLoading or onPageStarted never gets called.

you should use -

```
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url)
{
     if(url.startsWith("https://m.youtube.com/watch?"))
     {

         setVideoIdFromLink(url);
         view.stopLoading();
     }
}

public String setVideoIdFromLink(String url)
{
    //get the video id from the link
    String[] args=url.split("v=");
    String videoId=args[args.length-1];

    return videoId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to extract Youtude Id

```
String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url); //url is youtube url for which you want to extract the id.
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group();
}
```

in webview

```
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("TAG","called overide url");
            if (url.startsWith(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL)) {
                String pattern = "(?<=watch\\v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";

                Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    String id = matcher.group();
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("GABI","url:"+url);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: the problem is that the method isn't being called at all - meaning the code that you mentioned isn't going to be reached (i dont see Log.d("TAG","called overide url"); massages once clicking the clip), i think it has something to do with javascript used to load the page